# Package not getting installed by apt-get

Tags: linux, installation, linux-mint, apt-get, apt

I am running `sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4`. I would expect this command to install the library, as there is no such library to be found when running `pkg-config --list-all | grep gtkmm`. However, when the install command is run, I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a' for regex 'libgtkmm-2.4'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

I then run the commands `rpm -ql libgtkmm`, `rpm -ql libgtkmm-2.4` and `rpm -ql libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a`, all of which say `package &name& is not intalled`.

Any explanation as to why it is not installing, or any tips on getting it installed? Thanks!

UDPATE:
I have tried other avenues, and I am running into an issue where another way of installing is asking for `atk`, which has the exact same problems as outlined above, but for `atk` instead of `gtk`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the RPM package tools if the system used the Debian deb packages. If you're installing with `apt-get` and not `yum`, then you need to use `dpkg` to check the packages instead of `rpm`.

To show the files in an installed package, use `dpkg -L packagename`. In your case use `dpkg -L libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a` as libgtkmm-2.4 doesn't exist.

Comment: in my case i am trying to install flycapture2 in ubuntu 16.   dependency libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a is not available and libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 is suggested as a replacement .... however it is not a replacement and I still cannot install my program (flycapture2).  at least your above dpkg -L command is successful; dpkg -L libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 ... letting me know where it is installed.  not sure where to go from here but hope this helps someone.  considering downgrade to ubuntu 14